# edit target attribute inside of iframe with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, target

we are using an application called LibWizard hosted on an external domain, the app is being used for a tutorial that is displaying content from my companies domain in an iframe.

Within that content are a bunch of links that have target="_top" on them, Id like to either change or delete this target attribute. First questions, is this even possible? I have read some things on Stack Overflow that suggest this wont work due to the two different domains.

Assuming this will work the iframe code looks like this

```
<iframe id="iframe_div" name="Frame for Navigate around the Roadmap (page 2 of 7)" title="Frame for Navigate around the Roadmap (page 2 of 7)" allowtransparency="false" src="https://www.library.unisa.edu.au/referencing-roadmap/" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms allow-pointer-lock" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0">
```

and the links that I want to edit are within a similar html structure to that of

```
<div class="column">
 <ul>
  <li><a title="Email" href="/referencing-roadmap/electronic/email/" target="_top">Email</a></li><li><a title="Australian Bureau of Statistics (online publication)" href="/referencing-roadmap/electronic/australian-bureau-of-statistics-online-publication/" target="_top">Australian Bureau of Statistics (online publication)</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

the jQuery I am currently trying to make work is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#iframe_div").on('load', (function(){
     $("#iframe_div").contents().find("li > a").attr('target','_self');
     }));
      console.log('text')
   });
```

Many thanks for any clues
Sam

Comment: Is the website in the iframe the same protocol, domain, and port of the page that the iframe is on?

Comment: The page in the `<iframe>` only has one `<a ...target="_top">` and it's in a `<div>`., Besides that, did you want these changes to be permanent, or just for whoever is on the other side of  of the `<iframe>`? Regardless, you'll need editing privileges on both pages.

Comment: @Taplar the website in the iframe is not in the same domain, hence my thinking this is not even possible?

Comment: @zer00ne I left out the rest of the <li> content to keep the code short, there are a whole bunch though. I don't want the changes to be permanent, only when the page is rendered.

Comment: @IcantCode If the domain is different, no, you will not be able to access it with javascript, as that would be a form of XSS (cross site scripting) and could be used maliciously.

Comment: @Taplar thanks I thought this was likely the case